# How to dynamically get the value from the checkbox list

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I have a checkbox list which displays list of account ids for the employees to retrieve individual records.

```
<c:forEach var="id" items="${accountList}" varStatus="status">
<input type="checkbox" name="account_id"  value="${id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

The name = account_id is declared as a string array list.

After selection , i will submit the results to the struts form and store the results in string array list.In the submit script , i need to check on the length of the account id selection and add in the count.finally submit the values to the form.

How to achieve this .kindly anyone help..

Thanks

Comment: I am a newbie on using this forum - Is there anything wrong with the question or should i need to be more elaborate.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you need the count of the values selected, you can have following either of two approaches.

- When a http request contains a name with multiple values (in your case `account_id`), then list is passed as comma separated list of values against that name. Servlet APIs offer a very convenient method of retrieving the values.

  `String accountIds = request.getParameterValues("account_id");`

This will get you the array containing list of account ids. The length of array(`accountIds.length`) should give you the count of account ids selected.

- Alternatively, you can track the account ids selected using **javascript**. On every select of the checkbox, increment a `counter` which is set as a `form hidden-field`. When the form is submitted, the hidden fields can be retrieved as request parameter.

Comment: Hi santhosh , thanks for your reply.Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: I have listed two approaches, which one you need help for ?

Comment: I prefer the second one to be used.

Comment: @ pikrut , thanks.Any coding would be fine for me .between could you please share an example for the same scenario which would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateTextArea() {         
        var allVals = [];
        $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox_name]:checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('#hidden_value').val(allVals);
}
$(function() {
        $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox_name]').click(updateTextArea);
        updateTextArea();
});
```

'checkbox_name' is the name of checkbox

```
allVals.push($(this).val());
```

This will push the value of checkbox to hiddenfield with id 'hidden_value'
if you need to insert 'id' of checkbox instead of value then

```
allVals.push($(this).attr('id'));
```

So you need to place the input field hidden with name and id inside the form

Then in your action page get the value from this input field hidden.
split this with"," separator you will get one array.The contents of array will be the values you checked and size will give you number of elements.

Otherwise

```
checked_count = $('[name="checkbox_name[]"]:checked').length
```

before form submitting 
calculate this and store in hidden field

```
$("#hidden_id").val(checked_count)
```

Get the value from hidden field in action page.

Comment: Hi Pikrut , i am trying out your example.I will let you know the result.Thank you..